# How to mine with Ethminer with parity enode

Tags: parity, ethminer, enode

I am a totally newbie in minning, a got and old nvdia gpu, parity fully synced and ethminer installed, windows 10, created two accounts with parity, but i dont know how to mine with ethminer and how to attach the parity enode to it...

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to set the destination address (where the rewards go). If you have an address already, great. If you don't, then you can make one in Parity with:

```
 $ parity account new
Please note that password is NOT RECOVERABLE.
Type password: 
Repeat password: 
ff25a05f8be3d4c9c58d35bd32cdbe4edd6515e6
```

You'll be asked for a password and be given an address. Once done, you should run parity and tell it to mine to that address when required. Supposing your address is `ff25a05f8be3d4c9c58d35bd32cdbe4edd6515e6`, then you would run:

```
$ parity --author ff25a05f8be3d4c9c58d35bd32cdbe4edd6515e6
```

Once Parity is running and synced with the network, you can start your miner of choice. For genoil, command would be:

```
$ ethminer -G
```

Where `-G` for GPU mining (opencl).

Since 1.6, Parity offers Stratum protocol support (beta). This protocol has number of advantages compared to the JSON-RPC polling, which results in better hashrate and less node strain. To run parity with Stratum on, use

```
$ parity --author ff25a05f8be3d4c9c58d35bd32cdbe4edd6515e6 --stratum
```

To utilize Stratum, miner also needs to be started in Stratum mode. For genoil, it will be

```
$ ethminer -G -S 127.0.0.1:8008
```

Comment: I have another question, how do I enter those commands after parity is already running?

Comment: You can't enable stratum at runtime, just restart your client.

Comment: Tried `ethminer -G`, but it says "At least one pool URL must be specified"

Comment: `ethminer -G -P stratum+tcp://127.0.0.1:8008` worked for me